# Use field from a nested class B as a column in a table of class A using OrmLite for Android

Tags: android, orm, ormlite, base-class

I have a "base" object (contains id, date created etc.) stored in an object that should be converted to database table. I want to merge the contents of base into concrete class, so that, e.g.:

```
public class Base {
    private long id;
    private long lastUpdate;
    private String type;
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "my_table")
public class Concrete {
    private Base base;
    private String name;
    private int etc;
}
```

will create a table with columns "id", "type", "lastUpdate", "name", "etc".

I know about linking using foreign keys, but in this case I don't want to create special table for base object (this is because id's in base object can be duplicate for different type), but instead merge its contents with "concrete" object's contents.

If this is not possible, what would you suggest as an alternative approach? I looked into composite keys, but it didn't look promising or efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have stumbled upon similar issue, I have found a decent solution to this issue :
In `Concrete` class, I added an annotation for `@DatabaseField` with property `useGetSet` set to `true`. The fields in the `Concrete` object are repeated from Base, but it my application that's acceptable (sole purpose of Base model is easy Gson parsing).

This way, instead of using the value of the member variable, the DAO will retrieve the value using property's getter and setter method. In the getters and setters I retrieve/set the values for the `Base` model. The result looks like this (for simplicity, only relevant items have annotations, omitting null checks etc.):

```
public class Base {
    private long id;
    private long lastUpdate;
    private String type;
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "my_table")
public class Concrete {
    private Base base;
    @DatabaseField(id = true, useGetSet = true)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int etc;

    public void setId(long id) {
         this.id = id;
         this.base.setId(id);
    }

    public long getId() {
         if(this.id == 0) {
               this.id = this.base.getId();
         }
         return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a "base" object (contains id, date created etc.) stored in an object that should be converted to database table. I want to merge the contents of base into concrete class...

If I understand your question, ORMLite *does* support base classes with database fields.  All you need to do is mark up the fields in `Base` with `@DatabaseField` annotations as well:

```
public abstract class Base {
    @DatabaseField
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField
    private long lastUpdate;
    @DatabaseField
    private String type;
}
```

Then you can extend `Base` instead of having a `Base` field in your sub-class.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "my_table")
public class Concrete extends Base {
    @DatabaseField
    private String name;
    @DatabaseField
    private int etc;
}
```

Comment: The naming I chose is a bit confusing (it's all coming down to Json structure this problem is stemming from), that's why i included an example. The problem is that the `Base` class is not being extended by the `Concrete` class, but is a member variable of the `Concrete` class. So far the best solution I found is to use the `useGetSet` property of the `@DatabaseField` annotation.